# JSON Parsing using Jackson/Gson Java

Tags: java, arrays, json, jackson, gson

I have the following Json

```
{
   "messages":[
      {
         "message":{
            "body":"Foo",
            "username":"XYZ"
         }
      },
      {
         "message":{
            "body":"HI",
            "username":"ABC"
         }
      }
   ],
   "response":{
      "status":200
   },
   "more":true
}
```

I build Custom classes My container class Result holds a List objects a Response object which contains a status and a boolean.

```
public class Message { 

  @SerializedName("body") 
  public String body; 

  @SerializedName("username") 
  public String username; 

  @Override public String toString() { 
    return "Message{" + "body=" + body + ", username=" + username + '}'; 
  } 
}

public class Response { 
  public int status; 
} 

public class SearchResponseST { 
  @SerializedName("messages") 
  public Message[] messages; 
  public Response response; 
  public boolean more;
}
```

In my main class I do:

```
SearchResponseST response = 
   gson.fromJson(reader, SearchResponseST.class); Message[] results = response.messages;
```

If I  eliminate the "message": and start the array directly, I am able to deserialize successfully using Gson.

How should I be parsing it with the current structure?

Comment: Post your POJOs to verify the structure.

Comment: public class Message { @SerializedName("body") public String body; @SerializedName("username") public String username; @Override public String toString() { return "Message{" + "body=" + body + ", username=" + username + '}'; } }

Comment: public class Response {
    public int status;
}
public class SearchResponseST {
  
      @SerializedName("messages")
    public Message[] messages;
    public Response response;
public boolean more;

Comment: In my main class: SearchResponseST response = gson.fromJson(reader, SearchResponseST.class);
            Message[]  results = response.messages;

Answer (score 0):

Though this does not answer your question directly, because I do not use Gson.  I have always used the org.json.simple package to parse JSSON.   you can read about it here: http://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/  Just throw the JSON into the parser, and get the data you want out.   Data is accessed just like you would access a HashMap (for JSONObject) or ArrayList (for JSONArray).

EDIT with parsing code:

```
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader("file.txt"));
    JSONArray array = (JSONArray) obj.get("messages");
    for (Object o : array) {
      JSONObject jo =(JSONObject)o;
      JSONObject messageObject = (JSONObject)jo.get("message");
      System.out.println(messageObject.get("body"));
      System.out.println(messageObject.get("username"));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am able to parse when the structure is as such:"messages":["msg 1","msg 2","msg 3"]
but not when messages contains "message" which contains the actual stuff. And this is incoming JSON which I would not be able to change.

Comment: I edited the code to show how I would go about doing this.  Again, I use a different JSON parser, but the idea is the same.  This code seems to get the message info fine.  You just need to keep track of what is an object and what is an array.

Comment: This approach looks like a DOM approach. Why I was trying Jackson/Gson was to be able to do full data binding. Hkwever, if that does not work, I might have to resort to the DOM approach.

Comment: yes, this is a type of dom approach, it seems you want to automate extracting the elements into your data structure.  Ultimately, the automation process will be doing something very similar, and just going through the hierarchy automatically.  Since the JSON is small in complexity, I personally would not worry too much about it, just extract it similar to the above and bind it how you want... as ultimately they are just hashmaps and arraylists, so you can just bind your own data structures to those via references.  It takes 2 mins to write the code above and you know it will work.

Comment: Yes. Actually I was looking to build a generic JSON parser that can parse any given JSON based on some configuration about its structure.

Comment: maybe I do not understand what you want to do, but isn't that is exactly what the many JSON parsers already do.  They take a JSON string (regardless of what its structure is) and create an object out of that. In the case of org.json.simple, it creates a set of ArrayLists and HashMaps.  That is exactly what a generic JSON parser does, so I do not know why you need to create a new generic JSON parser.  Now, what you do with the resulting Hashmap ArrayList is up to you, you can use the JSON object directly, you can encapsulate methods around it, or you then dump it into your own structure.

Comment: Why spend additional 2 minutes for writing monkey code when Jackson or GSON could do it automatically? Especially when result is slower than using data binding.

Comment: Here is what I am eventually trying to accomplish: For multiple data feeds, create Java classes dynamically using JavaCompiler which will be my POJOs & container classes. Then supply the Container class as input to GSON/Jackson such as gson.fromJson(reader, SearchResponseST.class); and have the Container populated. Currently I am trying to figure out if the structure of the JSON could be changed to facilitate this just as AhamedMustafaM's suggested structure.

Answer (score 0):

For a JSON like this

```
 {
       "messages":
        [
          {"body": "Foo", "username": "XYZ"   },
          {"body": "HI",  "username": "ABC"  }

        ],
        "response": {"status": 200 },
        "more": true
    }
```

try Container object designed like

```
Container { List<Message> messages;Response response;boolean more;}
```

BUT for the JSON you have posted, the Container object should be

```
Container { public HashMap[] messages;  public boolean more;    public Response response; }
```

Comment: I had tried List only earlier, but [Message{body=null, username=null}, Message{body=null, username=null}] This is the output

Comment: Again, for the Json you provided, it works. I have the problem when "message:" is nested inside messages as in the json provided.

Comment: Why do you want to use "message" inside `messages`? If that is the case , `messages` in `Container` must be `Hashmap` instead of `List`.

Comment: Thanks AhamedMustafaM the Array of HashMaps does it for the message inside the messages.

Comment: @aditya, You are welcome. You should accept the answer whatever you find fit after analysis.This will help you get better answers in future.